# Get key vault data from web activity in Data factory or Synapse workspace

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am working on a case on Azure Data Factory/Synapse Workspace making use of Key Vault to generate token for further use in the pipeline. I have followed an article using the principle getting clientid and secret from a web activity. But in the guideline the author is using the same setup in both activities resulting of course that the same outcome or output. Can anybody tell what to do so I can get clientid from one of the activities in the pipeline

https://www.hubnet.cloud/2021/05/17/part-2-reporting-on-log-analytics-data-building-the-query-and-extracting-data-using-azure-data-factory/

[image]

Comment: It's not the same setup. One activity gets the client ID and the other the client secret.

Answer (score 0):

**To get the details from key vault you have to crate two secrets one is `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`.**

[image]

Then fetch the details from web activity in ADF by passing below values for each secret in web activity.

```json
URL : [Your secret URI value]?api-version=7.0
Method : GET
Authentication : System Assigned Managed Identity
Resource : https://vault.azure.net
```

[image]

And you will be able to access all the values.

**Reference:**  [Use Azure Key Vault secrets in pipeline activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-use-azure-key-vault-secrets-pipeline-activities)